# How to combine multiple JSON encoders for passing to `json.dumps`?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Say you've got multiple encoders, like this:

```
class JsonDataClassEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    Supports dataclasses
    """
    def default(self, o):
        if dataclasses.is_dataclass(o):
            return dataclasses.asdict(o)
        return super().default(o)


class JsonEnumEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Enum):
            return obj.name
        return super().default(obj)
```

Is there a way to combine them, without subclassing them, such that it would be possible to use

```
json.dumps(opj, cls=MultipleJsonEncoders(JsonEnumEncoder, JsonDataClassEncoder))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MultipleJsonEncoders():
    """
    Combine multiple JSON encoders
    """
    def __init__(self, *encoders):
        self.encoders = encoders
        self.args = ()
        self.kwargs = {}

    def default(self, obj):
        for encoder in self.encoders:
            try:
                return encoder(*self.args, **self.kwargs).default(obj)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        raise TypeError(f'Object of type {obj.__class__.__name__} is not JSON serializable')

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        enc = json.JSONEncoder(*args, **kwargs)
        enc.default = self.default
        return enc
```

Usage

```
import json
import enum
import datetime

class JsonDateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date)):
            return o.isoformat()
        return super().default(o)


class JsonEnumEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Enum):
            return o.name
        return super().default(o)

class Enumm(enum.Enum):
    X = enum.auto()

obj = {'time': datetime.datetime.now(), 'enum': Enumm.X}
encoder = MultipleJsonEncoders(JsonDateEncoder, JsonEnumEncoder)

In [502]: json.dumps(obj, cls=encoder)
Out[502]: '{"time": "2020-12-23T08:51:43.646022", "enum": "X"}'
```

Comment: To the point!  (and works like a charm)

Maybe helpful if you provide a little more textual (background) information ..... e.g. why do you need the __call__ ?

Comment: `MultipleJsonEncoders` should inherit from `JSONEncoder`. I think to do so you just need to add a `super()` call to the `__init__` and you can get rid of the `__call__` entirely

Answer (score 0):

@tsorn's answer is great, I adapted it to strict type hinting as follows:

```
from json import JSONEncoder
from typing import Any, Type

class CombinedEncoder():
    """
    Combine multiple JSON encoders
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338261/combine-multiple-json-encoders
    """
    def __new__(cls, *encoders: Type[JSONEncoder]):
        def default(o: Any, *args: bool, **kwargs: bool) -> str | Any:
            for encoder in encoders:
                try:
                    return encoder(*args, **kwargs).default(o)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
            raise TypeError(
                f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} is not JSON serializable')

        encoder = type(
            "CombinedEncoder",
            (JSONEncoder,),
            {
                "default": default,
                "__doc__": "Combines JSONEncoders"
            }
        )
        return encoder
```

Comment: This works well for situations where proper typing is necessary, but I think `__new__` tends to be a bit harder to understand and use properly, I suggest an alternative approach using the factory pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76931520/7088038)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a more functional approach: most json dump/load functions support the `default` argument. A look into the docs of the [original source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ac4ddab405a36bd0e2b86bcd147b3a647b734492/Lib/json/__init__.py#L72) reveals how to use it:

```
>>> import json
>>> def encode_complex(obj):
...     if isinstance(obj, complex):
...         return [obj.real, obj.imag]
...     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {obj.__class__.__name__} '
...                     f'is not JSON serializable')
...
>>> json.dumps(2 + 1j, default=encode_complex)
'[2.0, 1.0]'
>>> json.JSONEncoder(default=encode_complex).encode(2 + 1j)
'[2.0, 1.0]'
>>> ''.join(json.JSONEncoder(default=encode_complex).iterencode(2 + 1j))
'[2.0, 1.0]'
```

This allows it to use simple functions instead of subclassing everything. [Now you can combine encoders via a higher-order function](https://bargsten.org/python/io/#combine-encoders).

```
def combine_encoders(*encs):
    def combined(obj):
        for enc in encs:
            try:
                return enc(obj)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        raise TypeError(f"Object of type {obj.__class__.__name__} is not JSON serializable")

    return combined

combined_encoders = combine_encoders(encode_complex, encode_path)
encoded = json.dumps(data, default=combined_encoders)
```

For me the result looks a bit simpler, because you don't need to understand why a `def __call__` definition is needed in the class-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

The [currently accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420151/7088038) using a `MultipleJsonEncoders` class works but somewhat abuses the interface, because functions like `json.dumps` really should be passed an instance of `json.JSONEncoder`. This becomes apparent when you start writing type annotations for surrounding code.

To do this with proper typing you can do something similar to the `MultipleJsonEncoder` solution, but wrapping the class in an abstract factory method that produces a properly typed JSONEncoder subclass as the "multi encoder":

```
def multiencoder_factory(*encoders):
    class MultipleJsonEncoders(json.JSONEncoder):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.encoders = [encoder(*args, **kwargs) for encoder in encoders]
            
        def default(self, o):
            for encoder in self.encoders:
                try:
                    return encoder.default(o)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
            return super().default(o)

    return MultipleJsonEncoders
```

this produces the desired behavior when serializing objects via multiple encoders. For example:

```
import json
import enum
import datetime

class JsonDateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date)):
            return o.isoformat()
        return super().default(o)

class JsonEnumEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, enum.Enum):
            return o.name
        return super().default(o)

class Enumm(enum.Enum):
    X = enum.auto()

obj = {'time': datetime.datetime.now(), 'enum': Enumm.X}
encoder = multiencoder_factory(JsonDateEncoder, JsonEnumEncoder)

json.dumps(obj, cls=encoder)
```

produces `'{"time": "2023-08-18T11:23:26.626274", "enum": "X"}'`.

Not only that but `encoder` is a valid subclass of `json.JSONEncoder` as we expect

```
In [2]: isinstance(encoder(), json.JSONEncoder)
Out[2]: True
```

Note also that unlike some of the implementations suggested in other answers we only create instances of the sub-encoders once, exactly when we create an instance of the parent `MultipleJsonEncoders` class.

Theres a small amount of additional work you could do to polish things up- for example the str representation of the returned class is pretty messy and could use a `__str__` or `__repr__` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing. I have pursued code, but the module is not made to be accept multiple classes. If it can, how it decide order of encoders? You must use subclassing.

Comment: `how it decide order of encoders` by the order they are passed to `MultipleJsonEncoders`