# How to pass two JSONEncoder classes to the `cls` parameter of json.dumps?

Tags: python, json

I want to serialize class instances to JSON, but my class contains UUID and datetime members so I get this TypeError.

> TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

I succeeded to solve each problem (the UUID and datetime problems) individually by creating classes for each member:

```py
class DTEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

class UUIDEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, uuid.UUID):
            # if the obj is uuid, we simply return the value of uuid
            return obj.hex
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And I use the classes like this:

```py
convertedReadObject=json.dumps(ReadObject,cls=UUIDEncoder)
```

ReadObject has UUID member.

But now I need to do this but I need to pass two classes to the `cls` parameter.

Comment: I think.. you need to [combine your 2 custom encoders into 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65338261/2745495).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple JSON encoders for passing to \`json.dumps\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338261/how-to-combine-multiple-json-encoders-for-passing-to-json-dumps)